# Linksys router gives good IP to wireless client but not to wired client

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, wired-networking

**Setup:** I have a Linksys WRT54G router running DD-WRT. I changed the router's IP address from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.2.1 and set a Wi-Fi password, but other than that it's a default DD-WRT with wireless enabled and DHCP. For now I have not connected my router to another network. It's just a router with an Ethernet cable connecting my machine to the #1 port (I've tried #2, #3 and #4 as well).

**Problem:** This router used to provide valid IP addresses for both wired and wireless clients. I turned off this router for a while and just got it out again and now my Windows 7 machine can't get a good IP address on a wired connection, though wireless works fine on the same machine and router.

**Details:**

`ipconfig /all` for wired:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-34-56-78-90-AB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.132.98(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I realize that the 169.254 IP address is an APIPA address assigned by the machine to itself that means it couldn't get an IP from the router. But I don't know why the machine can't get an IP from the router. (FYI 255.255.0.0 is the subnet mask for my corporate network to which I usually have a wired connection.)

`ipconfig /all` for wireless on the same router:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1504 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CD-EF-12-34-56-78
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.105(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, May 18, 2015 11:13:15 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, May 19, 2015 11:13:15 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Restarting the router
- Different Ethernet cable
- Hard reset of router (DD-WRT is still on it)
- `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`
- `netsh int ip reset` (this told me to reboot Windows, which I did)
- A different laptop (my laptop has Windows 7, and this different one has Windows 8.1)
- Windows Firewall is turned off

**Question**: Why can I not get a valid IP address (192.168.2.x in this case) over a wired connection, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `ipconfig /release` and then `ipconfig /renew` on your ethernet-connected computer? You might also want to try resetting the network stack `netsh int ip reset`... Do other ethernet devices get valid IPs? Also try resetting your Windows Firewall to default settings...

Comment: Thank you, @BigChris. I have tried your suggestions but they didn't seem to change anything. I will edit my list of things I have tried accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the router for a couple of weeks. Today I turned it on, plugged it into the same laptop with the same Ethernet cable, and got a valid IP address. I have no idea why the problem fixed itself, but I'm all set. Good things come to those who wait, I guess.